# Find what plugin implements a functionality in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Most eclipse platform functionality is implemented in plugins.

I'm trying to figure out what plugin/s is/are responsible for certain functionality or actions. In my case specifically, figuring out which ones are responsible for import resolution in java files:

for the line `import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;` eclipse will give me an error: `the import org.openqa cannot be resolved` (since I've never worked with openqa, and I haven't added it to my pom.xml file), while for the line `import java.util.Iterator` it just knows what we're talking about.

**How can I find and dissect those behaviors, to better understand how the resolution works?**

I know I can get a list of all installed plugins through: help -> about eclipse -> installation details -> plug-ins; but that isn't much help since that's just a huge list of suspects.

Conversely, I've tried running eclipse with `-vm c:\jre\bin\java.exe -consoleLog` to see the internal logs, but it looks like most plugins only log errors to the error log.

My guess is that using maven to enrich the project's build jars list, and some existing collection of multiple jars, eclipse will look in the project's build path to resolve the import. But that's just a guess...

Also, when the resolution fails, eclipse will give the `cannot resolve import` error, and allow me to figure it out through an import search window that doesn't actually find anything, which is what I'm trying to see it it's possible to improve upon.

Comment: Import resolution just looks at the things listed in the project 'Properties > Java Build Path'

Comment: To be clear, I want to identify the actual plugins, so that I can read their source code, and better understand how they work.

Comment: That is going to be a major project, this is not simple code. You could start by looking at all the uses of the `org.eclipse.jdt.core.classpathContainerInitializer` extension point which define the different types of containers used in the build path.

Comment: The [Eclipse plugin spy](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#plug-in-spy-for-ui-parts) might be interesting for you

Answer (score 0):

The Maven plugin definitely plays an important role for looking up Java classes. If you right click on a project in Eclipse you should see a menu item that is called Build Path. It shows the dependencies of the project that are taken into account when Eclipse builds classes in the project. A dependency can be a jar, but it does not have to be. The dependencies include Maven dependencies.

This post is not an answer to the general question of finding a plugin that implements a functionality, but it's maybe enough for your specific case.

Comment: Thanks, @mm759, but as you said, this doesn't answer my question. Sadly, your answer actually makes it less likely someone else will answer the question since it's no longer listed as "unanswered".

Comment: I gave the question an upvote to increase the chance of getting further answers. If one of the comments already solves the problem someone can transform it to an answer.